# How to fix exception Invalid memory access failed loading language in tess4j

Tags: java, arraylist, tesseract, bufferedimage, tess4j

I have a code where I read image text using Tesseract in java 8.

I even changed the Datapath to point within the source folder on eclipse but still getting this exception within that period of running the program.

How do I fix this problem? Should I dispose the BufferedImage if possible how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`setDatapath` should not be in the loop; it needs be called only once after the Tesseract instance is created. I would dispose of the instance and start a new one after so many OCR operations; otherwise, the memory leaks in the native code will eventually crash the JVM.

Comment: When using dispose(); the eclipse system says "create dispose method" does this method not internally available?